# How can you add properties annotated with PrimaryKey to existing RealmObject model objects in Realm .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, realm

I am using Realm .NET to store model objects in a realm database. I have an existing model object called `Employee` with a single property:

```
public class Employee : RealmObject
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

The Realm database already contains a few instances of this type.

I am now trying to add a new property to the object which should be annotated with the `[PrimaryKey]` attribute. The desired new version of the object should look like this:

```
public class Employee : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Since the new `Id` property will not contain suitable values for the existing database objects, I am trying to use the migration feature in Realm to seed their values. The code to perform the Realm migration looks like so:

```
private void MigrateToSchemaVersionWithEmployeeIds(Migration migration)
{
    var employees = migration.NewRealm.All<Employee>();
    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        employee.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

When starting the app, the migration code is executed but when assigning to the `Id` property, an `Exception` is thrown:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Once set, primary key properties may not be modified.`

As a workaround, I have determined that you can first add the property without the `[PrimaryKey]` attribute, have its values seeded in the migration code (no exception is thrown in this case), stop the app, add the `[PrimaryKey]` attribute to the property, increase the schema version and relaunch the app. As this is no workable solution for when an app is already deployed in production, I am looking for a way to achieve this without having to use such a workaround.

How can a property with a `[PrimaryKey]` attribute be added to an existing model object in Realm .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is unfortunately, not possible. As a workaround, you can map your `Employee` class to a new table like:

```
[MapTo("Employee2")]
public class Employee : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

It will allow you to keep using it as `Employee` for all intents and purposes, but in the database itself it will be persisted as `Employee2`. Then in the migration block, you could do:

```
private void MigrateToSchemaVersionWithEmployeeIds(Migration migration)
{
    var employees = migration.OldRealm.All("Employee");
    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        var newEmployee = new Employee
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Name = employee.Name
        };
        migration.NewRealm.Add(newEmployee);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know of the MapTo attribute, thanks for the heads-up! In your migration block, you only create new objects. Will the default migration delete the old objects since they are no longer mapped to by an entity class?

Comment: Then if I have .Net and ReactNative with sync, it means I will need to change table name in React Native as well. Sorry Realm, your migration process is the worst